# Implement "open with" for a text editor in C++

Tags: c++, text, gtkmm

I tried to make a simple text editor in C++ and gtkmm and I want to know how to open a text file with that program using "open with".
To be better understood let's say I have a text file called "test.txt" and I want to open that file with my program using "open with".

Comment: Does it accept command-line arguments?

Comment: @Shark:Yes it accept command-line arguments

Comment: GtkFileChooserDialog
http://www.gnu.org/software/guile-gnome/docs/gtk/html/GtkFileChooserDialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, this is a registry setting. You can modify the registry setting from within your program but other than that it's up to the OS to launch your program.

Comment: Ok, thanks Waldermort!